# Stubborn reappearing of .bin files in node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Every time I ran `yarn` or `yarn install` a yarn file appears at `node_modules/.bin` which is waaaay older than the current version and which I always have to manually delete. How can I prevent it from happening? Where is the info buried, that tell the file to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must somehow have gotten (an ancient version of) `yarn` installed in your `node_modules`.

From there, `yarn` links `yarn`'s executable ("bin") into `node_modules/.bin`; this functionality is briefly mentioned at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#executables, and described in more detail at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html#bin.

The command `yarn why yarn` should tell you which package(s) are responsible for `yarn` getting into `node_modules`.

Comment: I provided my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Now I know: WebStorm IDE has a pref setting to copy executables form `node_modules` into `.bin` directory in order to facilitate the usage of WebStorm's built-in terminal.

[image]

It acts like kind of an equvalent of `npx`. That's why my local version of yarn was still getting copied and overwrote the global installation.

Comment: It looks like you're misreading something; your package manager (which you appears to be yarn) has the responsibility of adding packages bin files to `node_modules/. bin` ... it looks like I still left out way too many details; sorry about that! That checkbox *does* help with some of the same use cases as `npx`, though. (The ones where npx doesn't end up installing any packages, to be specific.)